# Show branches not up to date with other branch

Tags: git

I'm creating a git alias to merge master to outstanding development branches after we've had a deploy.

I can find out which branches are not merged into master with this command: `git branch --no-merged master`. However, from that list, I can checkout the unmerged branch, and it's possible that the new commits from master have already been merged into it.

```
$ git branch --no-merged master
2019-01-20_resize-tracking
* 2019-03-27_D8-752_config-module
...

$ git checkout 2019-01-20_resize-tracking
Switched to branch '2019-01-20_resize-tracking'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/2019-01-20_resize-tracking'.

$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.
```

How can I find which branches are not merged in a given branch, and also not up-to-date with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
git branch --no-merged master --no-contains master
```

Which list the branches which are not merged in master and which don't contain master (so, which need to be updated).